# When will Google's Generative Language API be accessible in France?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp

When will Google's Generative Language API be accessible in France?

I know there is a work around but I would prefer this api.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no official information from Google about when the Generative Language API will be fully accessible in France.

The Generative Language API is only available in a limited number of regions, which doesn't include France. You can find the list of supported locations on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/learn/locations).